# Call-by-value of a c struct containing a pointer to heap allocated memory

Tags: c, struct, heap-memory

Dear stackoverflowers.

During some experimenting with c and structs, me and a friend of mine came across something we cannot quite get our heads around. Below is a code snippet describing a struct with an int pointer and a variable. They are both set whilst creating the struct in the main function.

We were wondering how c handles call-by-value on structs. Call-by-reference is all clear, simple reference and everything that is modified changes. Now the strange or interesting comes with the call-by-value. The struct is copied as a local variable and so are the pointer and the value of length in the struct. Basically creating another pointer to the same heap memory. (correct me if I am wrong).

No what if you free this pointer. Does that mean that you loose the information on there? Not necessarily, cuz the information might be still there and within your page. But What if you malloc the pointer again.

Why is the information still there? With and without the new malloc. Doesn't that mean that the OS gives you a new block of memory? Why is that value still there? What happens in general if you pass a struct call-by-value with a pointer to heap memory?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Struct
{
  int* array;
  int length;
} Struct;

void callByValue(Struct st)
{
  st.array[1] = 11;
  st.length = 11;

  /* This is weird */
  free(st. array);
}

void callByRef(Struct *st)
{
  st->array[1] = 22;
  st->length = 22;
}

int main()
{
  Struct s;
  s.array = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  s.array[1] = 0;
  s.length = 0;

  printf("Before array[1]: %d length: %d\n", s.array[1], s.length);

  callByValue(s);

  printf("Caal-by-value array[1]: %d length: %d\n", s.array[1], s.length);

  callByRef(&s);

  printf("Caal-by-reference array[1]: %d length: %d\n", s.array[1], s.length);

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Before array[1]: 0 length: 0
Caal-by-value array[1]: 11 length: 0
Caal-by-reference array[1]: 22 length: 22
```

Comment: Hmm, you are not going to find a lot of compilers that allocate the copy on the heap.  The stack is the common choice.  Regardless, this is big-time UB.

Comment: Because after malloc, you didn't write anything in that pointer before trying to print it. For whatever reason, malloc'ing again didn't change the where the pointer is pointing to. Anyway, it's UB, so anything can happen.

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong.  Your st parameter for callByValue() is copied on to the stack.  any changes you make to st or its members will be discarded when the function returns and the stack pointer is reset.

Comment: This is not true for the heap memory array and exactly this is the reason why we are interested in this particular issue.

Comment: Then again why is this UB? Because isn't it a natural thing to put heap allocation in structs? Don't we do this all the time...

Comment: It's perfectly natural to put heap allocation in structs, and it's done all the time. The only problem is accessing memory after calling `free` on that memory.

Comment: Another problem not mentioned yet; passing `s` by value when it contains an uninitialized member variable `array[0]` causes undefined behaviour due to read of indeterminate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call by value, the code makes a copy of the struct for use by the function. So you have this situation

```
main:        s.array  ---+
                         +---> MemA (memory for 2 ints)
callByValue: st.array ---+
```

After you `free(st.array)`, both of the pointers are invalid, since `MemA` has been freed.

After you `malloc(1000...)`, you have this situation

```
main:        s.array  ---> MemA (invalid pointer)
callByValue: st.array ---> MemB (memory for 1000 ints)
```

The pointer in `main` doesn't get updated and remains invalid. Using the pointer in `main` will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: However after we free, we are able to give the struct by reference to the other function and modify the array. Firstly we didn't malloc again and thought exactly what you describe. However we could just acces the pointer and change the data in the heap...

Comment: Yes, that's the problem with undefined behavior (UB). Sometimes your program appears to work, even when it's totally wrong. The C language provides no protection against UB, it's your obligation as a programmer to avoid UB. One of the tools that can help you find UB in your programs is [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). I suggest running your code with valgrind to see what errors you get.

Comment: Then why is it so that if I malloc space first, then free it, and then acces it that the os doesn't complain. Is this merely the page problem that comes into play? Cuz that would explain this issue.

Comment: The OS doesn't really care. You ask for memory with `malloc`. You relinquish control of the memory with `free`. After the `free`, the OS **may** use the memory for something else. If you use the memory after the OS uses it for something else, then anything can happen. Hence **undefined** behavior.